# How to get nearest place?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm using the code below:

I want to get the nearest place from google (only need nearest result).

To do this, I changed radius but then result is wrong.

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=6.384314,81.324417&radius=1000&types=accounting|airport|amusement_park|aquarium|art_gallery|atm|bakery|bank|bar|beauty_salon|bicycle_store|book_store|bowling_alley|bus_station|cafe|campground|car_dealer|car_rental|car_repair|car_wash|casino|cemetery|church|city_hall|clothing_store|convenience_store|courthouse|dentist|department_store|doctor|electrician|electronics_store|embassy|establishment|finance|fire_station|florist|food|funeral_home|furniture_store|gas_station|general_contractor|grocery_or_supermarket|gym|hair_care|hardware_store|health|hindu_temple|home_goods_store|hospital|insurance_agency|jewelry_store|laundry|lawyer|library|liquor_store|local_government_office|locksmith|lodging|meal_delivery|meal_takeaway|mosque|movie_rental|movie_theater|moving_company|museum|night_club|painter|park|parking|pet_store|pharmacy|physiotherapist|place_of_worship|plumber|police|post_office|real_estate_agency|restaurant|roofing_contractor|rv_park|school|shoe_store|shopping_mall|spa|stadium|storage|store|subway_station|synagogue|taxi_stand|train_station|trave_agency|university|veterinary_care|zoo&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyA0JD_Z2Uo2AfnDTejQFWHAXOIaRRpjF8c`

Answer (score 0):

Order the results by distance(by using the `rankby`-parameter):

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?**rankby=distance**&location=6.384314,81.324417&types=accounting|airport|......&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyA0JD_Z2Uo2AfnDTejQFWHAXOIaRRpjF8c](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?rankby=distance&location=6.384314,81.324417&types=accounting%7Cairport%7Camusement_park%7Caquarium%7Cart_gallery%7Catm%7Cbakery%7Cbank%7Cbar%7Cbeauty_salon%7Cbicycle_store%7Cbook_store%7Cbowling_alley%7Cbus_station%7Ccafe%7Ccampground%7Ccar_dealer%7Ccar_rental%7Ccar_repair%7Ccar_wash%7Ccasino%7Ccemetery%7Cchurch%7Ccity_hall%7Cclothing_store%7Cconvenience_store%7Ccourthouse%7Cdentist%7Cdepartment_store%7Cdoctor%7Celectrician%7Celectronics_store%7Cembassy%7Cestablishment%7Cfinance%7Cfire_station%7Cflorist%7Cfood%7Cfuneral_home%7Cfurniture_store%7Cgas_station%7Cgeneral_contractor%7Cgrocery_or_supermarket%7Cgym%7Chair_care%7Chardware_store%7Chealth%7Chindu_temple%7Chome_goods_store%7Chospital%7Cinsurance_agency%7Cjewelry_store%7Claundry%7Clawyer%7Clibrary%7Cliquor_store%7Clocal_government_office%7Clocksmith%7Clodging%7Cmeal_delivery%7Cmeal_takeaway%7Cmosque%7Cmovie_rental%7Cmovie_theater%7Cmoving_company%7Cmuseum%7Cnight_club%7Cpainter%7Cpark%7Cparking%7Cpet_store%7Cpharmacy%7Cphysiotherapist%7Cplace_of_worship%7Cplumber%7Cpolice%7Cpost_office%7Creal_estate_agency%7Crestaurant%7Croofing_contractor%7Crv_park%7Cschool%7Cshoe_store%7Cshopping_mall%7Cspa%7Cstadium%7Cstorage%7Cstore%7Csubway_station%7Csynagogue%7Ctaxi_stand%7Ctrain_station%7Ctrave_agency%7Cuniversity%7Cveterinary_care%7Czoo&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyA0JD_Z2Uo2AfnDTejQFWHAXOIaRRpjF8c)

**Note:**

- you must ommit the radius in this case
- there is no way to limit the number of results to a specific value